# Python: Tkinter LabelFrame: How to make the surrounding line of the LabelFrame expand with the window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The aim of my code is that the`LabelFrame-line`expands with the window. I already looked up several different solutions that work alone but not within the class I want to use.

The following is the code I wish to adapt (Code_1):

```
import tkinter as tk

class window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()

        # LabelFrame
        self.group = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="My first Label Frame")
        self.group.pack(expand="yes", fill="both")

        # Label inside LabelFrame
        self.label = tk.Label(self.group, text="Hello")
        self.label.pack()



root = tk.Tk()
app = window(root)
app.mainloop()
```

It gives me this Result: [Result_Code_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u59v2.png)

And this is the code that is working alone (Code_2):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="This is a LabelFrame")
labelframe.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")

left = tk.Label(labelframe, text="Inside the LabelFrame")
left.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[Result_Code_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTHX3.png)

**Question:**
What is causing the difference of behaviour between Code_1 and Code_2 and how can I modify Code_1 to act the same way as Code_2 does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the first one is inside a frame which is inside the root window itself. But the second one is directly inside the root window without being inside any container widget:

```
class window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
```

This means your widgets will inherit from the `Frame` widget as long as you make their parents `self`.
Add a `Frame` widget to your second code (whose parent is `root`) and make this the parent of the `LabelFrame` widget:

```
frm = tk.Frame(root)
frm.pack()

labelframe = tk.LabelFrame(frm, text="This is a LabelFrame")
labelframe.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")
```

Now you are getting the same view with the first code.
And in order to make Code_1 to act the same way as Code_2 does:
Change this:

```
class window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
```

to this:

```
class window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
```

And change this:

```
self.group = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="My first Label Frame")
```

to this:

```
self.group = tk.LabelFrame(master, text="My first Label Frame")
```

Also, change: `app.mainloop()` to: `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But I want Code_1 to act like Code_2 as stated in the question. Is there any way how to resolve this? Maybe replacing `tk.Frame`by something different?

Comment: Seems like you have not understand anything yet. In the first example, your widgets inherit from `tk.Frame`. Make them directly inherit from the root window by removing this section and change the parents of the widgets to the master window inside the class.

Comment: Yes it seems like. I just started with `tkinter` that day. Thanks again for anwsering my question.